# How to use OpenCV4's FastLineDetector in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, detection, segment

I'm trying to use FastLineDetector from OpenCV4 library in Python 3 in order to detect lines and segments from images but it seems that there is no way to make it work. I've read the documentation here : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d4c/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1FastLineDetector.html still nothing seems clear to me.
I've installed OpenCV 4.1.0 and I'm running Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.0.4.

Here is the code I've tried separately :

```py
img = cv2.imread('/tmp/output0.png', cv2.CV_8UC1)
fld = cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector.detect(img)
```

```py
fld = cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector.detect(cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector(img))
fld.detect(img)
```

Here are the output errors :

```
fld = cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector.detect(img)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'detect' requires a 'cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

```
fld = cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector.detect(cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector(img))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'ximgproc_FastLineDetector' or its derivative)
```

Does someone know how to use FastLineDetector or has an exemple ?

By the way, is there any difference with cv.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector() ?

Comment: What if you use `cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector().detect(img)`?

Comment: Still doesn't work. It shows me this error : ```cv2.ximgproc_FastLineDetector().detect(img)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'ximgproc_FastLineDetector' or its derivative)```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go

```
def FLD(image):
    # Create default Fast Line Detector class
    fld = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
    # Get line vectors from the image
    lines = fld.detect(image)
    # Draw lines on the image
    line_on_image = fld.drawSegments(image, lines)
    # Plot
    plt.imshow(line_on_image, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
    plt.show()
    return line_on_image
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks. For those who don't know, you need to have opencv-contrib-python to implement this code, not opencv-python.

Comment: @Doğuş, in case you're using Anaconda, their default [opencv](https://anaconda.org/main/opencv) package seems to include the contrib modules, so you don't need a special package.

Comment: can I get and analyze the single lines returned by the detector ? if yes , how ? , better how can I  feed only some lines to fld.drawSegments(image, lines)